# Laravel 5.3 Model Factories

Tags: php, laravel

Simple question about factories:

ModelFactory:

```
$myarray=[
'cat1',
'cat2', 
'cat3'   
];



 $factory->define(App\Job::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
        return [
            'title' => $faker->randomElement($myarray),
            'firm_id' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 3),
            'user_id' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 5),
        ];
    });
```

Why it's not working?

And another simple question: Is it possible to pass $myarray in factory from eloquent?

Comment: Which error is throwing?

Comment: Undefined variable: myarray

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the closure **use** your array, to make it available in it :)

```
$myarray = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'];

$factory->define(App\Job::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) use ($myarray) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->randomElement($myarray),
        'firm_id' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 3),
        'user_id' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 5),
    ];
});
```

Here is a few examples from the php docs :)
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-160